# Can I rename the Carousel in Twitter Bootstrap to avoid conflicts? If so how?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. I'm using the included carousel in one place on my website to rotate a list of DIVs, displaying one div at a time.

It's initiated like this:

`$('.carousel').carousel({interval: 5000});`

The Bootstrap Carousel is very very basic, and elsewhere in the site I need a carousel that allows me to display multiple items at once, add call-backs etc, so I want to use something like [jq.carousel](http://5509.github.com/jq.carousel/#sample) or [jQuery Carousel](http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm). Both these use the same function name as the Bootstrap one, and are initiated like this:

`var $carousel = $('.mycarouselclass').carousel();`

So... there's a conflict. What different ways are there to use both plugins on one site? Is there a way to redefine one of the plugins so that it's called with a different name? If you think think I'm approaching this problem in the wrong way please say so, I'm very open to suggestion and learning :)

**Additional info based on comments:**
I want to leave the minified plugin js files untouched if possible, so am interested in a way of renaming one instance externally so that future plugin upgrades are easy.

Comment: Yes you can. :) What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ok, I've added "If so how?" to the title. Asking questions on here is a bit of a minefield :)

Comment: Just rename method name in plugin file? :)

Comment: @egis Thanks, but is there a way to do it externally? I would like to leave the plugin js untouched for easy upgrading in the future. I'm going to add more info the the question to make this clearer.

Comment: bootstrap javascript components are available as individual files, just include the ones you need and remove the other ones.. https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/js

Comment: In that case, why don't you rename your function, which is under your control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you load in the second carousel plugin, you rename the function in the first one locally, like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="bootstrapCarousel.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $.fn.bootstrapCarousel = $.fn.carousel;
    delete $.fn.carousel;
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="nonBootstrapCarousel.js"></script>
```

Then if you wanted the bootstrap version you'd call `.bootstrapCarousel()` and for the other one it's just `.carousel()`.

Comment: Thanks Timm that exactly what I needed even though I didn't quite know how to ask for it :)

Answer (score 0):

While Timm's answer is still valid, Twitter Bootstrap plugins provide own `.noConflict()` method for avoiding namespace collision.

For TB 2.3.x, see [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#overview), and for the latest 3 follow [this link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). Both versions use the same method by the way.

```js
var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict() // return $.fn.button to previously assigned value
$.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton            // give $().bootstrapBtn the Bootstrap functionality
```

What I found by reading one of TB's plugin code is that the plugin preserves preloaded plugin which uses the same namespace in an internal variable `var old = $.fn.carousel` and puts it back when `.noConflict()` is called. It is convenient if the other plugin was loaded first and TB was loaded.

If you load TB first, you need to call `.noConflict()` before you load the other plugin that will use the same namespace. Otherwise later loaded one may occur errors.